# Windows Application creates several ClickOnce instances

Tags: visual-studio, clickonce

My application creates an instance of ClickOnce each time it's executed. Is this intended?, I tried to look up for any documentation but I have not come up with anything that explain this behaviour.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out. I was executing the published files instead of the shorcut made by the installation. Stopped creating new instances